# operator overloading as a friend

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I was trying to write a Complex number class , with overloading of the `operator + - *` as friend like below:

```
ComplexNumber operator+(const ComplexNumber &c1, const ComplexNumber& c2)
{
    return ComplexNumber(c1._r+c2._r, c1._i+c2._i);
}

ostream& operator << ( ostream &out,  ComplexNumber &c){
    out << c.getReal() <<'+'
        << c.getImg()  <<'I' << std::endl; 
}
```

I experience no problems while doing:

```
ComplexNumber c1(1,2);
cout << c1 << endl;
```

but when I try to do the following:

```
ComplexNumber c2(2,1);
cout << c1 + c2 << endl;
```

I get an error:

> no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘ComplexNumber’ to ‘ComplexNumber&’

I know the problem is that that the return value of the `operator+` is a `ComplexNumber`, but the `ostream` operator needs a `ComplexNumber&`.

I don't know how to deal with this. Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure you understand this, a `T` can be passed into a function taking a `T&` as long as it's an actual object, not just a temporary. All it does is take the actual object instead of copying it. One difference with `const T&` is that you can pass in a temporary, like the one you get after adding two. It will exist until the end of the full expression.

Comment: yeah, I get it, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why it would say argument 1, but you should make your output overload take a const reference:

```
ostream& operator << ( ostream &out,  const ComplexNumber &c){
                                      ^^^^^
```

It's better because a temporary can be used and you don't modify it.

Comment: Of course, this only works if `.getReal` and `.getImg` are `const` functions as well.

Comment: @Xymostech, Yeah, I was kind of waiting to see if that would come up. By all means they should be.

Comment: thanks so much, I even change all the friend function to class function to avoid this

Comment: @tintin, If you can access the real and imaginary parts from outside the class, the best solution is to do it like you did with them being friend functions, but without making them friends, and using the public access methods.